# number of real roots for each value of $t$ of a cubic polynomial

Tags: calculus

For each value of the parameter $t$, determine the number of real roots, counting multiplicities, of the cubic polynomial $p_t(x)=(1+t^2)x^3-3t^3x+t^4$.

Here 
$p_t(x)=(1+t^2)x^3-3t^3x+t^4$. So, $p_t'(x)=(1+t^2)3x^2-3t^3$ and $p_t''(x)=6(1+t^2)x$.

For $t \lt 0 $, $p_t'(x)=(1+t^2)3x^2-3t^3 \gt 0$  forall $x$. And Moreover for $t \lt 0$, as $x\to \infty$, $p_t(x) \to \infty$ and as $x \to -\infty$, $p_t(x) \to -\infty$. So it has only one real root

For $t=0$, $p_t(x)=x^3$.

For $t \gt 0$, $p_t'(x)=0$ gives $$x_*=\sqrt{\frac{t^3}{1+t^2}}$$ or $$x^*=-\sqrt{\frac{t^3}{1+t^2}}$$.

Since $p_t''(x_*) \lt 0$, minimum occurs at $x_*$.
Here I am getting stuck

Comment: See [cubic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#The_nature_of_the_roots).

Comment: can i do it without using the discriminant??

Comment: To do it this way you need to show that the local maximum value is greater than zero and the local minimum value is less than zero - then the intermediate value theorem strikes.

Answer (score 0):

For $t \leq 0$, the number of roots of this cubic polynomial is $1$.

For $t \geq \sqrt{3}$, number of real roots is $1$.

For $2-\sqrt{3} < t< 2+\sqrt{3}$, it is $3$.

For $t\geq 2+\sqrt{3}$, it's $1$.